# How can I "reset" the value of an observable before the results of an http call with RxJS?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have been getting into the habit of chaining RxJS observables together to compose my Angular view models.  For example, I would have some sort of BehaviorSubject for managing the values of the options on the page, and then pipe from there to construct the view.  I then subscribe to the view$ observable in the template using the async pipe.

What i'd like to do is set results to null after the options have changed, but before the results have returned from the API.  That way I can show some sort of loading message whenever there are no results, instead of having the results refresh abruptly, but delayed after user input.

```
private _defaultOptions: MyOptions = {
    page: 1,
    itemsPerPage: 50
}

private _optionsSubject: BehaviorSubject<MyOptions> = new BehaviorSubject<MyOptions>(_this.defaultOptions);


view$: Observable<MyView>;


ngOnInit(): void {

    const options$ = this._optionsSubject.asObservable().pipe(share());

    // Can I emit a null value here before the switchMap, and if so, will it be processed prior to the results from switchMap?
    const results$ = options$.pipe(
        swicthMap((options: MyOptions) => {
            var params = {
                skip: (options.page - 1) * options.itemsPerPage,
                take: options.itemsPerPage
            }

            return this.someApiService.list(params);

        }),
        shareReplay(1)
    );


    // Would I be better off doing a pairWise here on options, and if they've changed assume the results will too at some point?
    this.view$ = combineLatest(
        options$,
        results$
    ).pipe(
        map([options, results]) => {

            return {
                data: results,        // This is ultimately what I want to set to null if the API is in the process of being called
                options: options
            }
        })
    );
}
```

Is there some RxJS operator that I don't know about that can help me complete this task within a pipeline?

Also, I realize I could just have some sort of isLoading flag that I set in the component with a tap before and after the call, but that doesn't feel very clean when chaining all of these observables together (but may be the better/simpler option).

Comment: Have you considered adding `startWith(value)` after that `switchMap`? Also, I think that `shareReplay(1)` is redundant there.

Comment: I think you have the approach correct with the combineLatest and pairwise operators... However, your alternative to introduce the isLoading observable is cleaner and easier to understand in my opinion. It sounds like you want to use the null value of data to indicate that items are being loaded, being explicit with `loading$` will produce easier to read rxjs code. A plus is the view can better distinguish between no data as a result of the current search options vs. data is being loaded.